# How pass List of my controler to my list javascript ASP.NET using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a list of names that return from my controler, this list return a array string from my mongodb database.I try pass this list to a list javascript.

My javascript code until now:

```html
    <script>
  var listNames = [];
  
  @foreach(var itens in @Model.ListaNames){
  
     listNames .push(itens.name);
  }
 </script>
```

But i can't access my listaNames inside this foreach.

Comment: You are mixing a server side language with client side javascript. Each language runs in different environment at a different time. You can't mix them like that

Comment: Yes i can, and done  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you cannot mix client side and server side language like this; but in some case if you want to access the array or object or a simple variable of your model you can use following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.ListaNames));
    console.log(list);
</script>
```

Json.Encode convert your C# object or array to java script object

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

My solution, maybe is not the best way but work for what i want

```html
         var listNames = [];


        @foreach(var itens in Model.ListaNames){

            @:listNames.push("@itens.Name[0]");
            @:listNames.push("@itens.Name[1]");
            @:listNames.push("@itens.Name[2]");

        }
```